# What makes this first piece of code faster than this other one?

Tags: c++

First one:

```
string minRemoveToMakeValid(string s)
{
    stack<int> st;
    string S = s;

    int N = s.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (S[i] == '(') st.push(i);
        else if (S[i] == ')')
        {
            if (!st.empty()) st.pop();
            else S[i] = '\0';
        }
        
   }
  
    while (!st.empty())
    {
        S[st.top()] = '\0';
        st.pop();
    }
    string answer;
    for (char& ch : S)
    {
        if (ch != '\0') answer += ch;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Second one:

```
 string minRemoveToMakeValid(string s)
{
    stack<int> st;
   

    
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == '(') st.push(i);
        else if (s[i] == ')')
        {
            if (!st.empty()&&s[st.top()]=='(') st.pop();
            else st.push(i);
        }

    }
    
    while (!st.empty())
    {
        s.erase(st.top(), 1);
        st.pop();
    }
    
    return s;
    
}
```

I mean in the first one I'm making another string iterating over it at the end and I'm just not sure why the first one seems to be a good bit faster than the second one? Can anyone maybe explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

This loop is `O(n^2)`, where the rest of the alogithm (in both cases) is `O(n)`.

```
    while (!st.empty())
    {
        s.erase(st.top(), 1);
        st.pop();
    }
```

`s.erase()` is a fairly expensive function when deleting from anywhere but the end of the string.